# Why am I getting a 'missing $ inserted' error?

Tags: errors, compiling

I'm trying to compile this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}

\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{pifont,bbding}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xlop}

% Index
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

% Others
\usepackage{cancel,relsize}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl,subfigure}
\usepackage{stackrel}

% TikZ
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,calc,positioning,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,through,backgrounds}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Letras \mathbb
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb N}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb Z}
\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb Q}
\newcommand{\PP}{\mathbb P}

% Operadores
\newcommand{\mdc}{\operatorname{mdc}}
\newcommand{\mmc}{\operatorname{mmc}}
\newcommand{\sen}{\operatorname{sen}}
\newcommand{\dom}{\operatorname{D}}
\newcommand{\cdom}{\operatorname{CD}}
\newcommand{\ima}{\operatorname{Im}}
\newcommand{\idx}{\operatorname{id}}
\newcommand{\suchthat}{\;\ifnum\currentgrouptype=16 \middle\fi|\;}
\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{ocre}}

% Comandos
\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\tf}{\therefore}
\newcommand{\raw}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\lfraw}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\lfaw}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\ov}{\overline}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\input{structure} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template

\begin{document}


\chapter{Conceitos iniciais}
Neste capítulo, introduziremos definições e algumas propriedades da Geometria Plana que nos serão úteis ao longo deste livro. Apesar de algumas afirmações parecerem óbvias, elas nos auxiliarão tanto nas demonstrações de alguns resultados mais complexos quanto nas resoluções de exercícios propostos.

\section{Noções primitivas}
Na Matemática, a maioria dos conceitos são bem definidos, uma vez que, se tratando de uma ciência exata, não restem dúvidas para que propriedades e resultados sejam estabelicidos com total rigor.


\end{document}
```

But it makes this error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.76 Neste capítulo, introduziremos definiçõ
                                               es e algumas propriedades da ...
```

There's no math environment here, so why this happens?

Thanks :)

Comment: Your document is probably saved as UTF-8 and not as Latin-1; try with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` instead of `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`

Comment: Agreed with egreg. I've just tried with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and it works.

Comment: By the way, it's not a minimal working example… For example I had to remove the line `\input{structure}` to make it work.

Comment: You can edit your existing questions ...